# What does * before a Perl variable name mean?

Tags: perl

What does the Perl statement below mean?

```
*INPUT_DATA                    =\ 0;
```

I checked some Perl documentation sites also like https://perldoc.perl.org/variables, but I couldn't find a similar example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, `*` denotes a "typeglob", which is an internal type holding the values of all global variables of the given name. It's still sometimes used for filehandles in older code or to create aliases.

See [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata) for the explanation of typeglobs, and also see the links recommended at the end of the page, i.e. [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar), [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref), [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub), and [perlmod](http://p3rl.org/perlmod).

Comment: thanks, it seems in my project-related code its just used as another way to declare normal scalar variable but I see the value of using typeglobs.

Answer (score 2):

It create a read-only variable named `$INPUT_DATA` with value `0`. In other words,

```perl
*INPUT_DATA = \0;
```

is basically equivalent to

```perl
use Readonly;
 
Readonly::Scalar $INPUT_DATA => 0;
```

It is done through manipulation of the symbol table.

`*` denotes a glob aka typeglob which is basically a C struct that contain one of each type of variables (scalar, array, code, glob, file handle, directory handle, format, etc). The symbol table is a tree of globs.